# Input must be on for minimum 5 sec before thrue

Tags: python-3.x

I need a Input only to be thrue, if its on for 5sec. or more.
The input needs to be high for min. 5 sec to be  ==1:

```
if pfd.input_pins[0].value == 1:
    subprocess.Popen(["/my_script"])
```

Comment: All that has been posted is a program description. However, we need you to ask a question according to the [ask] page. We can't be sure what you want from us. Please [edit] your post to include a valid question that we can answer. Reminder: make sure you know what is on-topic here by visiting the [help/on-topic]; asking us to write the program for you, suggestions, and external links are off-topic.

Answer (score 0):

## As an object

A simple way would be to write a class which instances can be turned on and off, but which `__bool__` method returns `True` only if the instance has been on for a certain amount of time.

```
import time

class TimedBool:
    def __init__(self, delay):
        self._delay = delay
        self.on_since = None

    def set_true(self):
        if self.on_since is None:
            self.on_since = time.time()

    def set_false(self):
        self.on_since = None

    def __bool__(self):
        if self.on_since is None:
            return False
        else:
            return time.time() - self.on_since >= self._delay

b = TimedBool(5)
b.set_true()
print(bool(b)) # False
time.sleep(5)
print(bool(b)) # True
```

## As a property

If you need the timed value to be an attribute, you can use the same idea as above but with a property. The `__getter__` method of the property will always return a boolean and the `__setter__` method will register time.

```
import time

class Foo:
    def __init__(self, timed_bool_delay):
        self._timed_bool_on_since = None
        self._timed_bool_delay = timed_bool_delay

    @property
    def timed_bool(self):
        if self._timed_bool_on_since is None:
            return False
        else:
            return time.time() - self._timed_bool_on_since >= self._timed_bool_delay

    @timed_bool.setter
    def timed_bool(self, value):
        if value is True:
            if self._timed_bool_on_since is None:
                self._timed_bool_on_since = time.time()
        elif value is False:
            self._timed_bool_on_since = None
        else:
            raise ValueError('timed_bool property can only be set to a boolean')

foo = Foo(5)
print(foo.timed_bool) # False
foo.timed_bool = True
print(foo.timed_bool) # False
time.sleep(5)
print(foo.timed_bool) # True
```

Comment: Thanks for the info. How would the  script look like with this input?    if pfd.input_pins[0].value == 1:
    subprocess.Popen(["/my-script"]) If input pfd.input_pins(0).value   TIMER_ON?? ==1:    subprocess.Popen(["/my-script"])

Comment: @user3804654 No idea, you have to describe what `pfd.input_pins[0]` is.

Comment: pfd.input_pins[0].value, is form Pifacedigitalio, this is a Input on a Piface module. The script is  python3. Basicaly its a GPIO.

Comment: @user3804654 I gave it a try because the problem seems interesting, but you gave little information about your problem and showed no attempt so I cannot help you with that. Start by editing the question to describe what the `pfd.input_pins[0]` object is.

Comment: By the way, you need to be able to update the class of `pfd` to implement the above. You will likely need to inherit from it and extend it.

Comment: normaly with gpiozero  there would be a hold_time, do do what I need, but this is not avalible with Pifacedigitalio.

Comment: Add details in your question so other people can join in, I know nothing of those librairies you are mentionning

Comment: pfd.input_pins[0].value ==1: is the correct argument, it works, but I need this to be on for 5sec. to be thrue.

Comment: I am looking for a python code, that:  if input is high (1)  for 5 sec. or more, do my_script, if input is high but less than 5 sec. do nothing.

Comment: Read what I said above: edit your question with details.